# How to maintain TSS styles when changing height / toggling view visibility?

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

Consider an expanded and a collapsed View, one visible at a time, toggled on click events.

In a TableRowView, I can set the TableViewRow height and toggle between the expanded and collapsed Views. The views show, but the TSS styles are lost - for example, background color.

Here is an example Alloy project that demonstrates:

index.xml:

```
        <TableView>

            <TableViewRow id="row">

                <View id="staticSection">
                    <Label>static section</Label>
                </View>

                <View id="collapsedView" onClick="expand">
                    <Label>collapsed</Label>
                </View>

                <View id="expandedView" onClick="collapse">
                    <Label>expanded</Label>
                </View>

                <View id="staticRuler">
                </View>

            </TableViewRow>

            <TableViewRow>
                <Label>next row</Label>         
            </TableViewRow>

        </TableView>

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

index.tss:

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
},

"TableView": {
    separatorColor: 'transparent'
}


"#row": {
    layout: 'vertical'
}

"#staticSection": {
    height: 25
}


"#collapsedView": {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#dfd'
}

"#expandedView": {
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#fdd'
}

"#staticRuler": {
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#666'
}
```

index.js:

```
$.index.open();

function expand() {
    $.expandedView.visible = true;
    $.collapsedView.visible = false;
    $.row.height = 130;
}

function collapse() {
    $.expandedView.visible = false;
    $.collapsedView.visible = true;
    $.row.height = 80;
}

collapse();
```

How can I build an expand/collapse View that can be databound to an Alloy Collection and will keep its styling? If ScrollView or some other non-TableView element is better for this (ListView?), can you demonstrate a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to retain the styles when resizing by using this row style:

```
TableViewRow: {
    selectionStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewCellSelectionStyle.NONE;
}
```